# How can ia as admin, know de id of each user?

Tags: grafana

I there, i'm trying to query data by user. I know that anyone can change is user but not the user id. How can i know each users id (othe tne enter one by one and query it using select `'${__user.id}'`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi. Can i export de users list an their ID from grafana withou copy paste?